# Why /etc/rc.local starts same Python script twice?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I start my script with rc.local like this:

```
sudo python3 /home/pi/myscript.py &   # &-mark because of while loop
```

In terminal I write

```
ps aux | grep "/home/pi"
```

It shows me:

```
python3 /home/pi/myscript.py         # <-- What is this?
sudo python3 /home/pi/myscript.py    # <-- rc.local
```

If I remove that start line from rc.local file there are no scripts running then. Also user is root for both of them.
Is it really running my script twice at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case; the line:

```
python3 /home/pi/myscript.py         # <-- What is this?
```

is the `python` command, as run by the `sudo` command and the line:

```
sudo python3 /home/pi/myscript.py    # <-- rc.local
```

is the sudo command, as invoked by `rc.local`.

Using `ps -fe` it also displays the parent pid of the processes, and from that it is easy to see that the `python` command is a child of the sudo command (using a `sudo bash` example):

```
$ ps -fe | grep bash
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
    0 15095   481   0 10:18am ttys000    0:00.06 sudo bash
    0 15096 15095   0 10:18am ttys000    0:00.01 bash
```

so the parent of `bash` is pid `15095`, which is the pid of the `sudo` command that invoked bash.

Because `rc.local` script is already run as root, the `sudo` is not needed, so to avoid the situation of seeing apparently multiple copies, you can omit the `sudo` in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found out that rc.local does not need sudo because it is already running as root. So sudo is causing that.

```
sudo python3 /home/pi/myscript.py &   # &-mark because of while loop
```

Has to be changed to that:

```
python3 /home/pi/myscript.py &   # &-mark because of while loop
```

Comment: The reason you're seeing two entries is that one corresponds to the `sudo` command itself and the arguments it's taking, the second one is the actual python process.

Comment: So are those "What is this?" and "rc.local" in my question actually just opposite?

Comment: @Petesh can you make official answer so I can accept that. Because you are answering why that happens.

Comment: The `what is this` is the python script itself, having been launched by `sudo` as root. The second entry is the `sudo` command, as invoked by `rc.local`. As you have surmised, `rc.local` already runs as root, so the `sudo` is not needed. Looking at the parent pids helps track down who's doing what. `ps -fe` instead of `ps aux` lists the pid and parent pid, and that would show you that the `python` command is the child of the `sudo` command.